# Custom UIAction Sheets in iOS

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uiactionsheet, uianimation

I have a situation where on a click of a button, I want to animate a tableView from bottom, I tried using [CustomActionSheet sample](https://github.com/homeyer/CustomUIActionSheet) , but I felt it very complicated .Please tell me the possible  ways in which we can do it.

Comment: it's not a custom action sheet. The project is animating a view from bottom to the mid of screen.

Comment: And there is nothing which is complicated just try to understand. This sample is the simplest you can ever find in your entire life. I request you to give some time to it rather than just finding the exact solution to your problem. You have to manipulate this code according to your needs.

Comment: Hi,@InderKumarRathore, I used that code, Now what I have done is, instead of just a UIView, I have a UITableView, with custom Cell, which contains an image, and I want to update that image on the cells based on some conditions, So, I used [tableView reloadData] on ViewWillAppear, but the table is not refreshing.Can you tell me what is goin wrong

Comment: I can imagine your code but it can be due to two reasons either your table view is not visible or `tableView` is `nil`.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore, no, I have implemented themes, in my app, so when I change theme and then open this Table, the image icons on each cell should get change according to theme, but thats not happening.

Comment: Sorry can't imagine your code.

Comment: Hi @InderKumarRathore, can you try it out, a simple test case where the table cell images should get refreshed

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23130/discussion-between-ranjit-and-inder-kumar-rathore)

Answer (score 0):

First of all set your table view's fram out side the view and then add as subview After that give animation by changing frame like .....

```
CGFloat height = 100;
[yourTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, height)];
[self.view addSubview:yourTableView];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
     [yourTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480 - height, 320, 100)];
}];
```

Hope it will help you